# Custom winforms authentication against SQL Server: how to handle password expiration?

Tags: winforms, authentication, sql-server-2008-r2

We've got a project built on Winforms and Entity Framework 4.2 (code-first) and SQLServer 2008 R2.

In this project users must authenticate against the SQL Server using their username/password (from the login screen).

So there will be no "master" or "system" user and there will be no query to retrieve/compare the username/password: the process is already done using the login into the SQL Server.
The users will have their own SQL user accounts and it should be handled within the application.

However we've come across password expiration policy and it got us stuck in the dark.
How may we handle that? Specifically, how may we handle this when the account is already expired?

We have already handled the exception but we simply don't know how to change the password remotely for the user.

It's not about the user A changing password for B. It's about A changing it's own password because it has expired (and I cannot ask the users to login into the SQL Server Management Studio to do that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [ALTER LOGIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms189828.aspx) statement

However, note that this theoretically allows any user to change any other user's password provided they have the ALTER LOGIN permission, so you should ensure you make the user supply the old password too (which I believe is the default).

Out of interest, why didn't you go for Windows Authentication? That way the login expiry and password handling would be transparent to you.

Comment: Alter login requires me to be logged in AND to have the ALTER LOGIN permission. Using EntityFramework I cannot get logged because the password has expired so there is no way to run the statement. That's one problem. Second is that users cannot have the ALTER LOGIN priviledge.

And I need this system because there will be 3 types of authentication: system-only (with a "master" user), this (sgbd) and windows authentication. The customer must be able to choose.

Comment: You could run the ALTER LOGIN as a sql user that only has permission for alter login and doesn't expire. As the user still needs to know their own password, it shouldn't expose you to any additional risk.

Comment: It breaks the design of the application (users should authenticate themselves against the DB and that's all). I know it's possible to do this way (some sort of "master" user even with reduced priviledges) and it might be the only way to do so, but I'm looking into something else. I thought about something related to the connection string (maybe a way to send the new and old passwords) or an API from the SQLClient that could help...

Comment: Unfortunatley, the API wont help unless you run it as a new user. Once the old login has expired, you can't connect as them at all - hence the suggestion to connect as a different user. The same goes with the SQLDMO API's - who are you going to authenticate as? You could argue that by supplying their old password, users are still authenticating themselves, as the account re-enable and password change wont happen otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. I had to ask it anyway. AFAIK there *should* be way to do that but if not at all, than I'll just have to create some "management accounts" for log (write-only) and password policy (alter login only). Wondering if the approach will be secure... =) Thanks anyway.

Comment: The two main issues are: 1) Making sure the user is who they say they are, which you are enforcing via making them enter their old password, and 2) You have to think of a way to transport the ALTER LOGIN statement somewhere in an encrypted form (after all it contains passwords!). You could make an encrypted HTTP request to a web service that you own, and THAT could make the request to the DB, ensuring the knowledge of the service account doesn't leave your ownership, at least.

Comment: It's a winforms application. There is no HTTP request to web service. =)

Comment: I know, but that doesn't mean you can't have one - to keep all of the admin stuff separate from the client :-)

Comment: Accepted as answer. It's not what I was searching for but it can't be done other way so I'll just have to use a "master" login and do a ALTER LOGIN statement. Thanks.